# How to implement Text Animations with FFMPEG?

Tags: php, ffmpeg, effects, video-editing, ffmpeg-php

I want to achieve text animations in video. example given below

[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_sLeWcwBJ_s][1]

Is this possible with FFMPEG or there is any other way possible? i have implemented text in and out with FFMPEG but now i want to add animation effects. Is this possible?

Comment: Not like those.